# can we create multiple aws lambda function when using aws-serverless-express with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

We're using nodejs express application deploy in aws lambda function.
Can we create multiple lambda function using cloudformation file in expressjs application?
And how can we create multiple resources using cloudformation file?

Comment: What is your usecase?

Answer (score 0):

solved the issue by creating a proxy resources inside main resources

```
/Login
  /{proxy}
/User
  /{proxy}
```

This mechanism solved the issue for allowed to different resources communicate different lambda function.